# Stacking Rails query with limit

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I am trying to get a total of 25 associations from the database. I would like 15 to be with a count equal to 1 and the rest to have a count greater than 1 (so ten greater than 10).
I have tried the following:

```
def self.get_specific_array
  a = Association.limit(25) # I would like a total of 25 associations
  a.where(["count = ?", 1]).limit(15) # I would like 15 of the associations to have a count of 1
  a.where(["count > ?", 1]) # I would like the remaining 10 associations to have a count that is greater then 1
  a
end
```

Comment: What should happen if there are only 6 with a count of 1?

Comment: then the rest is filled in with associations that have > 1 and if both have 5 there should be 10 results total. thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the result arrays of queries:

```
a.where("count = 1").limit(15) + a.where("count > 1").limit(10)
```

Comment: perfect! thank you! just curious, would that be the most efficient way?

Comment: the most efficient way is probably to switch from using AREL to using SQL with a UNION operator to combine the two result sets